# Проблема с форматом столбца DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

У меня есть DataGrid с Автогенерацией.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Прописываю:

```
DataGrid.Columns[0].ClipboardContentBinding.StringFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
DataGrid.Columns[1].ClipboardContentBinding.StringFormat = "HH:mm";
DataGrid.Columns[2].ClipboardContentBinding.StringFormat = "HH:mm";
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Столбец 1 DataTable
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Почему неработает со столбцами 1,2

Comment: H:mm:ss попробуйте

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: @AntonNikolaev Мне надо время без секунд.

Comment: Быть может потому что у вас исходные данные для ячейки не в формате `DateTime`?

Comment: У меня тип солбца TIME(7)

Comment: Данные беруться из базы данных

Comment: TIME - это БД формат, а в каком формате они у вас загружена в `DataTable`, или что там у вас? Наверняка у первой колонки в БД формат отличается от двух других

Comment: @aepot Добавил в вопрос

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings

Comment: @aepot Благодарен, Вам, сработало

Comment: @aepot Можете написать ответ

Comment: Я даже не знаю, что сработало. `hh:mm`?

Comment: @aepot "hh\:mm"

Comment: А без бэкслеша точно не работает? `hh:mm` Кажется, проблема была в том, что у вас было `HH` вместо `hh`.

Comment: @aepot Нет, неработает. А hh я так пробовал.

Comment: Напишите тогда ответ сами, потому что я не уверен в том, как это работает. Спустя какое-то время сможете его принять, вдруг кому пригодится.

Comment: @aepot Вот сдесь форматы https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings

Comment: Я выше вам эту же ссылку кинул

Comment: @aepot Ой, ну да.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема была в `StringFormat` для `TimeSpan`.

Я заменил `HH:mm` на `hh\:mm`. И заработало.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]